# adminLTE already comes with bootstrap4?

Tags: bootstrap-4, adminlte

I would like to know if adminLTE already comes with bootstrap4? forgive me for my English

I starting to project in PHP, and I need incorporate adminLTE with bootstrap4 to my project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does (will), but the AdminLTE 3 is still in alpha (pre-release):
[image: AdminLTE alpha releases]

You can download the latest release here: https://github.com/ColorlibHQ/AdminLTE/releases

Comment: no problem,though, if you think my answer was satisfactory, please consider accepting it :)